# Как сделать так чтобы контент менял свое содержимое при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "меню" был блок меню, а блоск "basket" скрывался и наоборот

```css
html {
    background: yellow;
}

.menu {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 370px;
    background: red;
}

.basket {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 370px;
    background: red;
}

.block_mini {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 85px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
}

.btn {
    display: flex;
}

.btn_ {
    background: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.block_mini_1 {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 85px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="menu"> <!-- по нажатию на кнопку "меню" -->
    <div class="block_mini"></div>
    <div class="block_mini"></div>
    <div class="block_mini"></div>
    <div class="block_mini"></div>
    <div class="block_mini"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- <div class="basket"> 
    <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
    <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
    <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
    <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
    <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
  </div>
-->

  <div class="btn">
    <button class="btn_">меню</button>
    <button class="btn_">корзина</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Добавьте кнопкам дата атрибут, со значением равным классу каждого подменю, считывайте атрибут нажатой кнопки и открывайте подменю согласно этому атрибуту. Все остальные до этого момента - скрыть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var tabs = document.getElementById('main');
tabs.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  var hideElement = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');
  for (i = 0; i < hideElement.length; i++) {
    hideElement[i].classList.remove("active")
  }
  var showElemtn = document.querySelectorAll('div#' + ev.target.id + '')[0];
  showElemtn.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
html {
  background: yellow;
}

.menu {
  height: 70vh;
  width: 370px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
}

.basket {
  height: 70vh;
  width: 370px;
  background: red;
}

.block_mini {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 85px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
}

.btn_ {
  background: white;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block_mini_1 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 85px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
}

.tab {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="tab menu" id="link1">
      <div class="block_mini"></div>
      <div class="block_mini"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab basket" id="link2">
      <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
      <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
    </div>
    <div>

      <div class="btn">
        <button class="btn_" id="link1">меню</button>
        <button class="btn_" id="link2">корзина</button>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ну и небольшой лайфхак - как сделать это на чистом html-css (без js): создаёте два радиобаттона, скрываете их, в качестве кнопок стилизуете лейблы к ним и в зависимости от того, какой из radio выбран, открываете соответствующий блок - меню или корзину.

```css
body {
    background: yellow;
}

.menu {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 370px;
    background: green;
}

.basket {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 370px;
    background: red;
}

.block_mini {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 85px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
}

.btn {
    display: flex;
}

.btn_ {
    background: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
[type="radio"], .menu, .basket {
  display: none;
}
#menu:checked ~ .menu,
#basket:checked ~ .basket{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="menu" checked>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="basket">
 
<div class="menu">
  <div class="block_mini"></div>
  <div class="block_mini"></div>
  <div class="block_mini"></div>
  <div class="block_mini"></div>
  <div class="block_mini"></div>
</div>

<div class="basket"> 
  <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
  <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
  <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
  <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
  <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
</div>

<div class="btn">
  <label for="menu" class="btn_">меню</label>
  <label for="basket" class="btn_">корзина</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn_');

for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {    
        document.querySelectorAll('.items').forEach(function(el) {
            el.style.display = 'none';
        }); 
        
        document.querySelector(`.${this.dataset.menuName}`).style.display = 'block';
    });
}
```

```css
html {
    background: yellow;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}

.menu {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 370px;
    background: red;
}

.basket {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 370px;
    background: red;
}

.block_mini {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 85px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
}

.btn {
    display: flex;
}

.btn_ {
    background: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.block_mini_1 {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 85px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="items menu"> <!-- по нажатию на кнопку "меню" -->
      <div class="block_mini"></div>
      <div class="block_mini"></div>
      <div class="block_mini"></div>
      <div class="block_mini"></div>
      <div class="block_mini"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="items basket d-none"> 
      <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
      <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
      <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
      <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
      <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
    </div>  

  <div class="btn">
    <button class="btn_" data-menu-name="menu">меню</button>
    <button class="btn_" data-menu-name="basket">корзина</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

вместо `..style.display = 'none';` и `.style.display = 'block';` лучше завести класс в стилях и оперировать ими